# Trying to read JSON file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to read in a json file in my Objective-C application, but unfortunately I am getting a RuntimeException.  The exact error is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

My json file is called "Transactions.json

```
[{ "transaction": "300001", "date": "1/1/11", "type": "ABC", "status": "State1" },
  { "transaction": "300002", "date": "2/2/12", "type": "XYZ", "status": "State2" },
  { "transaction": "300003", "date": "3/3/13", "type": "ABC", "status": "State3" },
  { "transaction": "300004", "date": "2/2/12", "type": "XYZ", "status": "State2" },
  { "transaction": "300005", "date": "3/3/13", "type": "ABC", "status": "State3" },
  { "transaction": "300006", "date": "2/2/12", "type": "XYZ", "status": "State2" },
  { "transaction": "300007", "date": "3/3/13", "type": "ABC", "status": "State3" },
  { "transaction": "300008", "date": "2/2/12", "type": "XYZ", "status": "State2" },
  { "transaction": "300009", "date": "3/3/13", "type": "ABC", "status": "State3" },
  { "transaction": "300010", "date": "4/4/14", "type": "XYZ", "status": "State4" } ]
```

My method that reads in the file looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Custom code here...
        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        NSError *err = nil;
        NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Transactions" ofType:@"json"];
        NSLog(@"Hello: %@", dataPath);
        NSArray *transaction = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&err];

                NSLog(@"Transaction list: %@", transaction);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why is the NSData object coming up as null, when I am reading in the JSON file?  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Just for the record, I have tried checking for extraneous spaces in my JSON file, and tried placing the JSON file in different places within my application folder, and nothing has worked.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Is this iOS or OSx?  What is the value logged for "dataPath"?

Comment: And, in general:  Don't "chain" operations together.  Assign the NSData pointer to a temp variable and then use that temp to feed NSJSONSerialization.  Makes debugging much simpler.

Comment: And log what's in "err".

Comment: This is OSX.  I get, Hello: (null) as my output for dataPath.

Comment: Are you sure that Transaction.json is in your app's Resources directory?

Comment: It's in Supporting Files directory.  I don't have a Resources directory.

Comment: Is it added to your target?

Comment: Well then, your data path is bad.  No surprise that nothing loads.

Comment: So how would I correct this problem?

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your suggestion, I just realized that the file is not added to my target.  How do I add it, as I am having trouble doing it from my File Inspector.  It is showing the box as empty beside my target, but won't let me select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your source code and your comments I assume that the application is built as a
"Command Line Tool". In that case the "Target MemberShip" checkbox is actually 
disabled for custom resource files like your JSON file.

As a workaround:

- Go to the "Build Phases" of the target.
- Click on "Add Build Phase" and select "Add Copy Files".
- In the new build phase, click on `+` and select your JSON file.

For a command line tool, it does not seem to matter which "Destination" you choose.
I tested it with "Destination: Resources". The JSON file is copied in the same
directory that contains the executable file. Now

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Transactions" ofType:@"json"];
```

should return that path and you can read the file from your application.