# How to correctly pass a textfile to NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am learning Objective-C and I have a problem passing a textfile to NSFileManager class. I created new empty file "testfile" in the same directory where my program is, but NSFileManager somehow can't find this file. I don't know what the problem is:

```
NSString *fileName = @"testfile";
    NSFileManager *fileMgr;
    NSDictionary *attrib;

    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"%@",[fileMgr currentDirectoryPath]);

    // verifying the test file exists
    if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath: fileName] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"File doesn't exist");
        return 1;
    }
```

Here is additional screenshot from my program

[image]

Comment: And what is the current directory?  Is that file in that directory?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the screenshot you can see that I placed it in the same directory where the file is...if of course I correctly understood what the same directory means

Comment: I don't think you do.  Look at what directory the `NSLog()` call printed and compare that to where the test file is.  What you would normally do is include the file in app bundle then use `NSBundle` calls to determine where the app bundle is currently residing.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/17708041/1187415 for a description how to copy a file into the build directory, when building a command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's <s>very likely</s> certain that the file is not in the directory that the program is running in.  When you run a program from Xcode, it normally runs in the top level directly of your Xcode project.  The NSLog should tell you exactly which  directory.

Note that by default, Xcode has a top level directory for the whole project and sub directories for the code for each target.  So if your project is directly in your home directory, Xcode will run the program in

```
/Users/<your home>/prog36
```

but your text file (being in the target's directory) is in

```
/Users/<your home>/prog36/prog36
```

Note the two nested directories, both called `prog36`