# NSBundle works with iOS but NOT for OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, nsbundle

I am having a problem, I spent a night on it yesterday, any help would be very helpful !
I am new in **iOS APP** development.

I am developing a simple APP with a `sqlite` database that I imported to my project (by adding it in “build phase” > “copy bundle resources”)

This works for **COCOA Touch (iOS)** but **NOT for COCOA (OSx “command line APP”)**

My need is for an **iOS APP** so I could say "OK". But I really want to understand why it does not work for `OSX`!

Basically I used this code line (I tried others as well)

```
NSString *sqliteFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDatabase"
ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

when I breakpointed the `sqliteFilePath` has a very long path, when I see the size of that element it is equal to “0”.
Could someone help me.

Comment: make sure have you added file/image to NSBundle as group ? please read at http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/

Comment: yes I tried both without success

Comment: jus a question, does it make sense to speak about bundle for a command line APP ??

Comment: If your question is about a OS X command line tool then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706734/trying-to-read-json-file-in-objective-c.